# How can I define a data structure with dependency on something not defined yet?

Tags: python

I want to define a dictionary so that a function, say run(), being called with some mnemonic, it calls one of the member functions in the class. So I came up with the following:

```
class foo:
    dict = { 'f_func' : f, 'g_func': g }
    def f():
        pass
    def g():
        pass
    def run(self, n):
        # ... do something
        dict[n]()
```

Now the problem is the value in dict are member functions that haven't been defined yet. How can I achieve this?

Or any other way to work around?

Comment: Your `run` method won't work either, use `self.dict`..

Comment: Leaving aside the naming of the variable, you just need to populate the dictionary before calling `run(..)`. Where exactly is your problem here?

Comment: @Thrustmaster: the problem is that `f` and `g` are not yet defined when `dict` is being created.

Answer (score 5):

You define the structure at a later time, in this case in the `__init__` method to ensure you have *bound* methods:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = { 'f_func' : self.f, 'g_func': self.g }
    def f(self):
        pass
    def g(self):
        pass
    def run(self, n):
        # ... do something
        self.dict[n]()
```

Alternatively, look up the methods by name:

```
class foo:
    dict = { 'f_func' : 'f', 'g_func': 'g' }
    def f(self):
        pass
    def g(self):
        pass
    def run(self, n):
        # ... do something
        getattr(self, self.dict[n])()
```

You can always alter the class after the class definition has completed:

```
class foo:
    def f(self):
        pass
    def g(self):
        pass
    def run(self, n):
        # ... do something
        self.dict[n](self)

foo.dict = { 'f_func' : foo.f, 'g_func': foo.g }
```

but that stores unbound methods forcing you to pass in `self` explicitly.

Lastly, you could move the definition of `dict` to where the `f` and `g` functions have been defined:

```
class foo:
    def f(self):
        pass
    def g(self):
        pass

    dict = { 'f_func' : f, 'g_func': g }

    def run(self, n):
        # ... do something
        self.dict[n](self)
```

The class body is executed like a function would, with the local namespace turned into the class attributes. Now the `dict` values are functions, with the same problem as unbound methods; you need to pass in `self` explicitly. (In Python 3 there are no unbound methods anymore and this solution and the previous are equivalent).

You may want to avoid using `dict` as the attribute name, as it can cause confusion with the built-in `dict` type.

Comment: Yeah. I saw your update a bit late; I deleted my previous comment. +1